# Google Maps V3 marker with label

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How can I add label to my marker if my markers are populated on ajax success each result.

```
map.gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(result.latitude, result.longitude) });
```

I tried like this, but with no success:

```
map.gmap('addMarker', { 
    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(result.latitude, result.longitude), 
    'bounds': true,
    'icon': markerIcon,
    'labelContent': 'A',
    'labelAnchor': new google.maps.Point(result.latitude, result.longitude),
    'labelClass': 'labels', // the CSS class for the label
    'labelInBackground': false
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I doubt the standard library supports this.

But you can use the google maps utility library:

http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerWithLabel

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: myLatlng,
   map: map,
   draggable: true,
   raiseOnDrag: true,
   labelContent: "A",
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelInBackground: false
 });
```

The basics about marker can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

Comment: I am really new to this stuff so I am stuck. if I add the var marker, what is the map property for? the map canvas?

Comment: Thanks, the problem I guess is also that I use jquery-ui-map. Thank anyway!

Comment: Excellent stuff!  I didn't realise that there was a "MarkerWithLabel" class.

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu did you find a solution using jquery-ui-map?

Answer (score 56):

If you just want to show label below the marker, then you can extend google maps Marker to add a setter method for label and you can define the label object by extending google maps overlayView like this..

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var point = { lat: 22.5667, lng: 88.3667 };
    var markerSize = { x: 22, y: 40 };


    google.maps.Marker.prototype.setLabel = function(label){
        this.label = new MarkerLabel({
          map: this.map,
          marker: this,
          text: label
        });
        this.label.bindTo('position', this, 'position');
    };

    var MarkerLabel = function(options) {
        this.setValues(options);
        this.span = document.createElement('span');
        this.span.className = 'map-marker-label';
    };

    MarkerLabel.prototype = $.extend(new google.maps.OverlayView(), {
        onAdd: function() {
            this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.span);
            var self = this;
            this.listeners = [
            google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'position_changed', function() { self.draw();    })];
        },
        draw: function() {
            var text = String(this.get('text'));
            var position = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
            this.span.innerHTML = text;
            this.span.style.left = (position.x - (markerSize.x / 2)) - (text.length * 3) + 10 + 'px';
            this.span.style.top = (position.y - markerSize.y + 40) + 'px';
        }
    });
    function initialize(){
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);
        var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: gmap,
            position: myLatLng,
            label: 'Hello World!',
            draggable: true
        });
    }
</script>
<style>
    .map-marker-label{
        position: absolute;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

This will work.

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks man, you're awesome! I wish you'd get upvoted more, your answer is 100 % more thorough than tim's.

Comment: Definitely the best idea and answer here.
Keep in mind that it could use a better label positioning.
This class can also be used as a standalone label - without the marker.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks You answer help me. But I have one question here how to remove previously loaded label for multiple marker? Thanks is advance.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" for the line "google.maps.Marker.prototype.setLabel = function(label)..."  Google Maps API is loaded and working.  Adding markers works just fine yet accessing the Marker prototype fails.

Comment: Should definitely be the accepted answer. No plugin necessary, and it's easy to tweak for your specific needs. Thanks so much for the great solution!

Comment: Would be usefull for hide/show the MarkerLabel, add onRemove function:
`onRemove: function() {
            this.span.parentNode.removeChild(this.span);
        }`

Comment: still around Ramyani? Got a special case that gives me some problems.

Comment: This is perfect. a few tweeks here and there...works like a charm

Answer (score 9):

Support for single character marker labels was [added to Google Maps](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/labels-meets-markers-with-google-maps.html) in version 3.21 (Aug 2015). See the [new marker label API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel).

You can now create your label marker like this:

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(result.latitude, result.longitude), 
  icon: markerIcon,
  label: {
    text: 'A'
  }
});
```

If you would like to see the 1 character restriction removed, please vote for [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8578).

**Update October 2016:**

This issue [was fixed](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8578#c28) and as of version 3.26.10, Google Maps natively supports multiple character labels in combination with custom icons using [MarkerLabels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel).

Comment: still has extremely limited use. The current practical solution is very much still MarkerWithLabel (or some self-rolled implementation of that)

Answer (score 7):

The way to do this **without use of plugins** is to make a subclass of google's OverlayView() method.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#OverlayView

You make a custom function and apply it to the map.

```
function Label() { 
    this.setMap(g.map);
};
```

Now you prototype your subclass and add HTML nodes:

```
Label.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView; //subclassing google's overlayView
Label.prototype.onAdd = function() {
        this.MySpecialDiv               = document.createElement('div');
        this.MySpecialDiv.className     = 'MyLabel';
        this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.MySpecialDiv); //attach it to overlay panes so it behaves like markers
```

}

you also have to implement remove and draw functions as stated in the API docs, or this won't work.

```
Label.prototype.onRemove = function() {
... // remove your stuff and its events if any
}
Label.prototype.draw = function() {
      var position = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position')); // translate map latLng coords into DOM px coords for css positioning
var pos = this.get('position');
            $('.myLabel')
            .css({
                'top'   : position.y + 'px',
                'left'  : position.x + 'px'
            })
        ;
}
```

That's the gist of it, you'll have to do some more work in your specific implementation.

Comment: Sorry, but there are too many questionmarks in your code for it to be useful: 1) why the "var pos = this.get('position');" in your code, it's unused? 2) Where does the "g.map" refer in "function Label () {"? 3) No example on how to use the code? Should we replace "new google.maps.Marker()" with "new Label()"?

Answer (score 1):

You can now add a class name to the marker label via google.maps.MarkerLabel interface.
For example:

```
const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position_var,
      map,
      label: {
        text: 'label text',
        className: "my-label-class",
      },
      title: "Marker Title",
});
```

For a full list of options see the google map reference doc:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel