# Showing city names only for selected markers in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have set up "clean" map (with Google Maps API v3) with no labels in my website, now a user can select some cities from a dropdown menu and the markers of the selected cities should appear on the map also showing the name of the city as if it was part of the marker.
I can't use an InfoWindow because I need it for other informations, so is there a way to reach my goal?
Thank you in advance.

Here is a screenshot of what should appear when some cities are selected.

[image]

Comment: What's the hard part here, making certain markers show up in response to user input, or making the names appear above the markers, or both?  Show us some sample code for what you've got so far, so we've got something to work on.

Comment: Hi Duncan, I've added a screenshot of what I want to realize. As you can see I just want the name of the selected cities to be shown.

Comment: You need to use an Overlay. Check this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096094/google-maps-v3-marker-with-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Markers with Labels](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/examples.html) Library..Here is the code

```
labelAnchorPos = new google.maps.Point(25, 10); // you can adjust it as you require

marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
         position : new google.maps.LatLng(lat,.lon),
         icon : './img/img/yourIMG.png',
         labelContent : labelContentValue,
         labelAnchor : labelAnchorPos,
         labelClass : "labels", // the CSS class for the label
         labelInBackground : false
});
```

You can then show/hide labels of selected markers as required

Comment: Yeah, I did it that way. Thank you for your answer.