# How to show text (not icon) on map using google map data layer and geoJson file?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am able to show marker/icons using google map data layer and geoJson file(s). But instead of icons, is it possible to show a text (at particular location on map)?
It should not be part of InfoWindow. I am looking for something like [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb8uk.png)

I have tried using 'title' but it's just a label shown on mouse over of icon. Please help.

```
gmap.addListener('zoom_changed', function () {
    var gmapZoom = gmap.GetZoom();
    if (gmapZoom >= 0 && gmapZoom <= 21)
    {
        if (bJSONLoaded === false)
        {
            var setDataStyle = function (feature) {
                var status = feature.getProperty('status');
                switch (status) {
                    case "Active":
                        return {
                            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
                            title: 'test 1'
                        };
                    case "Pending":
                        return {
                            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png'
                        };
                }
            };

            pendingJSON.loadGeoJson('http://url/GoogleTestPending.json');
            pendingJSON.setStyle(setDataStyle);
            pendingJSON.setMap(gmap);
            activeJSON.loadGeoJson('http://url/GoogleTestActive.json');
            activeJSON.setStyle(setDataStyle);
            activeJSON.setMap(gmap);

            bJSONLoaded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!testJSON.getMap()) {
                console.log('setting map');
                pendingJSON.setMap(gmap);
                activeJSON.setMap(gmap);
                testJSON.setMap(gmap);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (bJSONLoaded === true && testJSON.getMap() != null)
        {
            //remove pins
            pendingJSON.setMap(null);
            activeJSON.setMap(null);
            testJSON.setMap(null);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338998/how-to-add-text-label-in-google-map-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096094/google-maps-v3-marker-with-label

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using OverlayView.

customEntity.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

And then implemented required functions like draw, onAdd, onRemove, etc.